# Compiled opencv 4.5.1 only works in (windows) anaconda - why?

Tags: python, opencv, build, anaconda

I have been trying to install opencv 4.5.1 with cuda support on my windows 10 machine.
Following guides at
https://jamesbowley.co.uk/accelerate-opencv-4-5-0-on-windows-build-with-cuda-and-python-bindings
and https://haroonshakeel.medium.com/build-opencv-4-5-1-with-gpu-cuda-support-on-windows-10-without-tears-cf0e55dc47f9

I had it working under an Anaconda environment but I wanted to try and eliminate Anaconda from the mix
so I re created (make and build / install) without using an Anaconda environment and the result doesnt work. it gets

```
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing cv2: The specified module could not be found.
```

I have fed my resultant cv2.cp38-win_amd64.pyd into `Dependencies` and `dependency walker` and nothing jumps out
The old dependancy walker only found 2 modules with no path `HVSIFILETRUST.DLL IESHIMS.DLL` but these are still there on the working version too.
(other than everything with API-MS-WIN-* and EXT-MS-WIN) the newer Dependencies didnt seem to find anything useful.

Both worlds are using Pyhon 3.8

```
Non-Anaconda = Python 3.8.10 (tags/v3.8.10:3d8993a, May  3 2021, 11:48:03) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Anaconda = Python 3.8.8 (default, Apr 13 2021, 15:08:03) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32
```

using James Troubleshooting tips https://jamesbowley.co.uk/accelerate-opencv-4-5-0-on-windows-build-with-cuda-and-python-bindings/#troubleshooting

```
where opencv_world451.dll
where opencv_img_hash451.dll
where nppc64_11.dll
where cudnn64_8.dll
```

all report valid modules AND the exact same modules are reported in and out of Anaconda environment

My theory is that there is something in the Anaconda 'environment', probable the Python environment that enables this to work
I started to debug by 'trimming' the anaconda environment but there are over 400 packages
plus I have a lot of confusion over what `python -m pip list` shows (about 215 things) and
what `help("modules")` shows. Just over 700 in the anaconda env vs 315 in my normal non-anaconda world
so thats over 400 modules/packages to sort through.
Then a lot of these things cannot apparently be removed - eg the whole 'brain' set of modules, dont know what they do but they have names that make them suspects

Haroon's post only seems to work under Anaconda but there is no reason why this should be so.
It seems just a personal preference.

Any Ideas ?
Thanks
JC

Ok I give up.
Thats about 20 builds with all the different combinations of OpenCV versions, Python versions,
Building with and without static libraries, with and without the 'world'.
With anaconda installed but not used and with anaconda completley uninstalled.
The result is always the same

```
import cv2
    ImportError: DLL load failed while importing cv2: The specified module could not be found.
```

That is any attempt to re-build Open-CV **WITHOUT** Anaconda fails.
And when you look at the resultant file (something like 'cp38-win_amd64.pyd') in Dependancies there are no missing modules except some obscure things deep in the windows tree

So it doesnt want to play and wont let me into its secrets so I will just have to live without CUDA thats 2304 cuda cores going to waste!
but the more I think about it the less I want Anaconda in the mix on what is essentially my office computer.
JC

Comment: all I can think of is a clean build... and making sure PATH contains what it should, and not what it shouldn't (anything anaconda?), for this situation.

Comment: Hi, I have the exact same problem, I am unable to import cv2 with same error. I tried installing opencv-python and opencv-contrib-python version 4.5.1.48. it does import cv2 but cuda build isn't linked with it. thus throwing cuda errors. Like you I am also struggling to find a solution. I hope you have found it.